# installation issue for Qliksense on my Windows 7

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to install Qliksense on My windows 7 64 bit but could not do it, i always get the error as shown below. I do have .net framework already installed in my system.

Installation error:

[image: installation error]

please let me know what's the problem so that i can resolve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make sure your post is useful without the image. Can you paste the error as text?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your current .net version, and reinstall a new.
Verifies that the version is 4.5.2

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42642